# Circle CI Workflows unarchiving cache not found

Tags: github, continuous-integration, circleci, circleci-2.0

I created configuration for Circle CI:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  dependencies:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v2-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - v2-dependencies-
      - run: yarn install
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
            - /root/.cache/Cypress
          key: v2-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
  test:
    docker:
      - image: cypress/base:10
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v2-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - v2-dependencies-
      - run: ls -la
      - run: yarn cy:cache
      - run: yarn cy:ci
      - run: yarn report:coverage

workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - dependencies
      - test:
          requires:
          - dependencies
```

What I expect:
It should first install all dependecies and cache it to use these dependecies in future jobs (e.g. for testing)

What happens:
It installs all dependecies and caches it, but in *test* job it unarchiving caches but not in same directory where test runs.

Output of ***ls -la***:

[image]

Output of cypress command:
[image]

**What I did wrong. How to use cache from previous job correctly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **same image** to use the cache, because every image uses different directory. At this example you are trying to get the cache from wrong directory.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  dependencies:
    docker:
      - image: cypress/base:10
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - dependencies-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
            - dependencies-
      - run: yarn install
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
            - /root/.cache/Cypress
          key: dependencies-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
  test:
    docker:
      - image: cypress/base:10
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - dependencies-{{ checksum "yarn.lock" }}
            - dependencies-
      - run: yarn cy:cache
      - run: yarn cy:ci
      - run: yarn report:coverage

workflows:
  version: 2
  build:
    jobs:
      - dependencies
      - test:
          requires:
          - dependencies
```